# Box collider dont recognize rigidbody in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, mesh-collider

Why is my person walking through trees?

How can my character go through a tree when my character has a rigidbody/mesh collider and my tree prefab has a box collider? I want the tree to act like a barrier

colliders don't detect each other, I want the tree to act as an obstacle

[image: fox inspector]
[image: tree inspector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check theese:

1. Check if collider component is active & working on your fox & tree (because that's marked removed)
2. in Physics window, check that player's & tree's layers can have collision with each other

Comment: I don't know how to do these is there a video where I can learn

Comment: [This link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) to check the 2nd thing I said

Comment: thanks, it worked when i changed its layers

Answer (score 0):

im assuming you are painting the trees on the terrain. If so then remove the Terrain collider in the Tree1 prefab and then refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to assign **Terrain Data** because its look like none.

Comment: i checked this, but still dont work

Comment: Then, you need to more specific about that.